# Inspecting RESTful web services using IntelliJ

Tags: web-services, rest, intellij-idea

I am working on a microservices application that has a webapp backend consuming a RESTful web service endpoint.

I use IntelliJ and I would like to see the traffic (requests, responses, headers, etc.) between the webapp backend (the client) and the web service endpoint.

How is that possible?

Note:

- I have tried using the bundled REST Client but it is just meant to issue requests to a web service endpoint.
- The chrome console is of no use either because it just monitor the traffic between the SPA and the webapp backend...
- My webapp and endpoint are developed in Spring/Java.

Comment: Why would intellij be able to do that? How would intellij be able to do that? You need some sort of logging proxy between the client and server (client being your webapp in this case) -- is that what you expect IntelliJ to do?

Comment: I was thinking about a IntelliJ plugin... Can you recommend an external tool then?

Comment: Nginx should do it, if configured correctly. There should be plenty of examples on the web.